# saving Urls to list

Tags: list, url, beautifulsoup

I want to make a list of urls I have gotten from a webpage, I know it's simple but I can't get my head around it (had a headache since yesterday lunch!)

Anyway here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
webpage = request.urlopen("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/IncidentsPast7days.cfm?siteCategoryId=3&T1ID=26&T2ID=35")
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
incidents = soup.find(id="CollapsiblePanel1")
for line in incidents.find_all('a'):
            link = line.get('href')
            Links = Links + Link
```

I know it isn't working but I'm not sure how to make it lol sorry and thanks in advance!

Raif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
for line in incidents.find_all('a'):
    link = line.get('href')
    Links = Links + Link
```

To this:

```
Links = []
for line in incidents.find_all('a'):
    Links.append(line.get('href'))
```

Comment: just another quick one lol, if i want to add some text to the begining of each item in the list i tried using for item in links[], append("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/") but that isn't working... I'm trying to turn each item into a valid link that i could then open and search for text. any ideas? I've look around but nothing makes it CLEAR lol

Comment: @RaifJackson: You can simply do `Links.append("your_prefix"+line.get('href'))`.

Comment: as you seem to be good with beautiful soup i was wondering if you could help me out with a kind of follow on issue ha ha. basically i have got the full link, gone through the same steps to get the div id from the new pages, but when i try and search for a specific fire station within that text i get None as the output.... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547287/string-search-returns-none-or

Comment: @RaifJackson: My answer above had nothing to do with `BeautifulSoup`, it was simply a matter of Python syntax that you were missing... But I'll have a look at it...

Comment: @RaifJackson: Sorry, but I'm unable to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` after installing it.

Comment: Thats ok thanks for trying! Ill keep plugging away lol @barakmanos