# string search returns none or []

Tags: html, string, list, search, beautifulsoup

I have several urls that i want to open to a specific place and search for a specific name but I'm only getting None returned or [].

I have searched but cannot see an answer that is pertinent to my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

webpage = request.urlopen("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/IncidentsPast7days.cfm?siteCategoryId=3&T1ID=26&T2ID=35")
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
incidents = soup.find(id="CollapsiblePanel1")
Links = []
for line in incidents.find_all('a'):
    Links.append("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/"+line.get('href'))
n = 0
e = len(Links)
while n < e:
    webpage = request.urlopen(Links[n])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
    station =  soup.find(id="IncidentDetailContainer")
    #search string
    print(soup.body.findAll(text='Ashburton'))
    n=n+1
```

I know its in the last link found on the page.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ouput is "[]" only, it means your output is an array. You have to set the index then => variable[index].

Try this one

```
print(soup.body.findAll(text='Ashburton')[0])
```

...where storing it into a variable first would be easier:

```
search = soup.body.findAll(text='Ashburton')
print(search[0])
```

This will bring you the first found item.

For printing all found items you could go

```
search = soup.body.findAll(text='Ashburton')
foreach(entry in search)
    print(entry)
```

***Notice this is more pseude-code instead of a working example.*** I really dont know beautifulsoap.

Comment: Thanks but it says list index is out of range. also if i change it to find and not findAll it returns None. sorry for the delayed answer i was at lunch :-p

Comment: If there is no entry in "search", then search[0] will give the out-of-range exception, right! 2 ways here: Put it into a try-catch statement or use an if-statement (if(search.Count>0)). If var_dump() is available, you could better use it (var_dump(search)) to get an output of everything. Just to check what exactly is stored in the variable.

Comment: thanks i know whats in the variable it is:  <div id="IncidentDetailContainer"><p>The Fire Service received a call reporting a car on fire at the above location.  One fire appliance from Ashburton attended.</p><p>Fire crews confirmed one car well alight and severley damaged by fire.  The vehicle was extinguished by fire crews using two breathing apparatus wearers and one hose reel jet.  The cause of the fire is still under investigation by the Fire Service and Police.</p><p> </p><p> </p></div> : and it IS there lol

Comment: is it possible that the returned text from the div id is not being looked at as a string and that is why i cannot search it? i have also now tried if 'Ashburton' in station but this also returns none... very puzzling

Comment: In general, if you search for a substring inside a text, the result will be a needle - the position of the first character-. So you cant compare `if result = "text"`. I dont know enough about beautifulsoup to get the problem in here. The only thing I could do is giving hints as I already did, sorry.